# try to malloc a struct array, but get heap buffer overflow

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I am new to programming and have just learned C shortly. Now my problem is, i tried to malloc a struct array, and then use it to fill in some information. but keep getting the heap overflow error report.
here is my declaration of struct in the h.file.

```
typedef struct llnode {
  char llnodename[256];
  int ll_index;
  struct llnode* next;
} llnode;
//the struct of a linked list.

typedef struct node_stru {
  char nodename[256];
  int node_index;
} node_stru;
//the struct of the node.
```

and the pointer:

```
node_stru *node_list = (struct node_stru*)malloc(n_nodenumber*(sizeof(node_stru)));
```

but later when i wants to use the linked list to fill in some information,it give me the heap overflow.

```
llnode* ptr=Ahead;
while (ptr!=NULL){
  printf("the name%s, the index%d", ptr->llnodename, ptr->ll_index);
  strcpy(node_list[n_index].nodename, ptr->llnodename);
  node_list[n_index].node_index = ptr->ll_index;
  n_index++;
  ptr = ptr->next;
}
```

The error report: I do malloc a 4*(256+4) memory, but it still not working.

```
0x619000000490 is located 0 bytes to the right of 1040-byte region [0x619000000080,0x619000000490)
```

Comment: Show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them, for example by showing us a [mcve]. Also please include possible input to your program, or hard-code the values for variables such as `n_nodenumber`.

Comment: There's nothing stopping the loop from walking off the end of `node_list`.

Answer (score 0):

You've allocated a fixed size for `node_list`, but there's nothing stopping your loop from walking off the end. For example, if `n_nodenumber` is 4 you can store 4 nodes. But if `Ahead` is linked to 5 nodes it will walk off `node_list`. That's assuming `n_index` starts at 0.

At minimum your loop should [`assert(n_index < n_nodenumber)`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_macro_assert.htm) to provide a better error when the loop walks off the array. That's all I can say without seeing a complete example.

Comment: Thanks, but the n_nodenumber is the result from linked list, linked list has 4 nodes, the node list also has 4 nodes to be filled in.